# Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 Error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I try to install Visual Studio 2012 Update 3. Currently I have Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 installed. 
When I try install Update 3 I get error:

> Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 (KB2707250) has stopped working. A problem
>   caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the
>   program.

No log files is created.
Maybe someone has the same problem with Update 3?

Comment: Did you update the running devenv.exe? Try to reboot the box and start the sp3 update as administrator without starting devenv.exe first.

Comment: Yes, I try this but it doesn't work.

Comment: I try to download iso Update 3 but it doesn't work too :(

Comment: Did you try uninstalling Update 2 before installing Update 3? That worked for me. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 8):

Delete all files/folders in C:\ProgramData\Package Cache ("%ProgramData%\Package Cache") 
and then rerun the installation of Update 3 (I used the ISO).
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/jj572486.aspx

Installing the Windows App Certification Kit will get past this.

Comment: link style answer is not suggested

Comment: hm, just installed the thing, but still experiencing that problem

Comment: This answer provided here doesnt seem to pertain to the issue at hand at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue every time I tried to run from the ISO image. I looked at the log file and noticed these two lines:

> Acquiring package: WinACK_native_x64_en, payload: WinACK_native_x64_en, copy from: 
>   F:\packages\WinACK\Windows App Certification Kit Native Components-x64_en-us.msp
>
> Acquiring package: WinACK_x64_x86_en, payload: WinACK_x64_x86_en, copy from:
>   F:\packages\WinACK\Windows App Certification Kit x64-x86_en-us.msp
>
> and then noticed the pipe errors:
>   **Error 0x800700e8: Failed to write message type to pipe.**

So I did a little more digging and it seems they had an answer for this same question over on [MSDN, Error when installing VS 2012 Update 3 - The pipe is being closed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fc126a0-74ab-4b6f-a924-a1222620f489/error-when-installing-vs-2012-update-3-the-pipe-is-being-closed)

Anyways, these steps worked for me (I used the [VS2012.3.iso](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update) image) on Windows 7 64-bit):

1) I did a repair first, because I was having issues (but I don't think that's required). Programs/Features > Visual Studio 201 > Right-Click, "Change" > Repair and rebooted.

2) Next, mount the ISO image with whatever tool you have, open explorer and go to the "F:\packages\WinACK" folder.

3) Run both as admin:

- F:\packages\WinACK\Windows App Certification Kit Native Components-x64_en-us.msp
- F:\packages\WinACK\Windows App Certification Kit x64-x86_en-us.msp

4) Once those have finished running, re-run the "VS2013.3.exe" file.

After that everything ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution suggested by Microsoft:

> To resolve this, you first need to download the complete .iso file for
>   the update 3 from this direct link
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301705
>
> Once you have this downloaded, and extracted/mounted/burnt you need to
>   open an administrative CMD window and navigate to ...\packages\WinACK\
>   and install these 2 patches:
>
> I. Windows App Certification Kit x64-x86_en-us.msp
>
> II. Windows App Certification Kit Native Components-x64_en-us.msp
>
> Having installed this, you can then run the setup for Visual Studio
>   2012 Update 3 using the same .iso file that you had downloaded.
>
> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2013/08/02/installation-of-visual-studio-2012-update-3-fails-with-error-the-pipe-is-being-closed.aspx

Anyway it wasn't working for me, I tried to repair Visual Studio as well, but no way...

So I did completely reinstall Visual Studio 2012. After that Update 3 has been successfully installed. I was installing Update 3 from iso file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still experiancing the same issues try following:

If you get "Pipe Closed" error during installation, you can try following order:

1. {{.\packages\WebDeploy*.msi}}
2. {{.\packages\WinACK\Windows App Certification Kit Native Components-*_en-us.msp}}
3. {{.\packages\WinACK\Windows App Certification Kit *-x86_en-us.msp}}
4. VS2012.3.exe

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running internet install instead of DVD install. I copied VS2013.3.exe from dvd to hard drive and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to work around the issue by doing the following:

- Close VS Setup (if it is running)
- Go to “Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features”.
- Double click the “Microsoft Visual Studio 2015” entry.
- Choose “Modify”. VS Setup will download the latest list of optionally installable content.
- At the top of the list of optional items you should see “Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (New)”.
- Check it and click the Update button to install VSUpdate 3.