# Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 installation Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with update 2 and have been trying to install Visual Studio 2012 Update 3.

I have tried every thing suggested here at the following links but with out any luck

1. [Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424824/visual-studio-2012-update-3-error)
2. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3fc126a0-74ab-4b6f-a924-a1222620f489/error-when-installing-vs-2012-update-3-the-pipe-is-being-closed

NOTE: I am installing from the offline installation ISO from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301705

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the log file (the error message contains a link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the steps mentioned in this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2013/09/23/the-pipe-is-being-closed.aspx

Comment: When linking to your own blog, it's nice to at least say you are the writer. Also, link only answers are a no-no on Stackoverflow.